# Theano fails due to NumPy Fortran mixup under Ubuntu

Tags: numpy, scipy, gfortran, theano

I installed [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/) on my machine, but the nosetests break with a Numpy/Fortran related error message. For me it looks like Numpy was compiled with a different Fortran version than Theano. I already reinstalled Theano (`sudo pip uninstall theano` + `sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps theano`) and Numpy / Scipy (`apt-get install --reinstall python-numpy python-scipy`), but this did not help.

What steps would you recommend?

#### Complete error message:

```
ImportError: ('/home/Nick/.theano/compiledir_Linux-2.6.35-31-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-10.10-maverick--2.6.6/tmpIhWJaI/0c99c52c82f7ddc775109a06ca04b360.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_write_done'
```

#### My research:

The [Installing SciPy / BuildingGeneral](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/BuildingGeneral) page about the `undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_write_done'` error:

If you see an error message

`ImportError: /usr/lib/atlas/libblas.so.3gf: undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_write_done`

when building SciPy, it means that NumPy picked up the wrong Fortran compiler during build (e.g. ifort).

Recompile NumPy using:

`python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95`

or whichever is appropriate (see `python setup.py build --help-fcompiler`).

But:

```
Nick@some-serv2:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy$ python setup.py build --help-fcompiler
This is the wrong setup.py file to run
```

#### Used software versions:

- scipy 0.10.1 (scipy.test() works)
- NumPy 1.6.2 (numpy.test() works)
- theano 0.5.0 (several tests fails with `undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_write_done'`)
- python 2.6.6
- Ubuntu 10.10

### [UPDATE]

So I removed numpy and scipy from my system with `apt-get remove` and using `find -name XXX -delete` of what was left.

Than I installed numpy and scipy from the github sources with `sudo python setpy.py install`.

Afterwards I entered again `sudo pip uninstall theano` and `sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps theano`.

Error persists :/

I also tried the `apt-get source` ... + `apt-get build-dep ...` approach, but for my old Ubuntu (10.10) it installs too old version of numpy and scipy for theano: `ValueError: numpy >= 1.4 is required (detected 1.3.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc)`

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, and after reviewing the source code, user212658's answer seemed like it would work (I have not tried it). I then looked for a way to deploy user212658's hack without modifying the source code.

Put these lines in your [theanorc](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#envvar-THEANORC) file:

```
[blas]
ldflags = -lblas -lgfortran
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to recompile NumPy from the sources?

I'm not familiar with the Ubuntu package system, so I can't check what's in your `dist-packages/numpy`. With a clean archive of the `NumPy` sources, you should have a `setup.py` at the same level as the directories `numpy`, `tools` and `benchmarks` (among others). I'm pretty sure that's the one you want to use for a `python setup.py build`.

**[EDIT]**

Now that you have recompiled `numpy` with the proper `--fcompiler` option, perhaps could you try to do the same with `Theano`, that is, compiling directly from sources *without* relying on a `apt-get` or even `pip`. You should have a better control on the build process that way, which will make debugging/trying to find a solution easier.

Comment: @Framester, as said, if you just installed python-numpy you do not have the files for building it. You will need to apt-get source ...+ apt-get build-dep ..., _then_ compile and install. To make it 100% clean with ubuntu, you may want to build a package, no idea needs to be done for that though.

Comment: I am still struggling installing numpy by hand. Unfortunately http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Linux is offline atm.

Comment: Thanks again for you tips. I tried to follow them, but I still receive the same error. See update. (already +1 for both)

Comment: Oh, I just saw, that I overlooked the apt-get source ...+ apt-get build-dep version. I am trying that right now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution I found is to add a hack in theano/gof/cmodule.py to link against gfortran whenever 'blas' is in the libs. That fixed it.

```
class GCC_compiler(object):
   ...
    @staticmethod
    def compile_str(module_name, src_code, location=None,
                    include_dirs=None, lib_dirs=None, libs=None,
                    preargs=None):
        ...
        cmd.extend(['-l%s' % l for l in libs])
        if 'blas' in libs:
            cmd.append('-lgfortran')
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I cannot test it, as I re-installed everything to get it working. +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

A better fix is to remove atlas and install openblas. openblas is faster then atlas. Also, openblas don't request gfortran and is the one numpy was linked with. So it will work out of the box.