# Theano installation problems on a cluster

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano

I am trying to install Theano on a cluster node running "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.10 (Tikanga)". I do not have admin permissions on the cluster. Hence, I installed Theano on my local user profile. The following are the version details of my installation:

> 1. The Python version is : Python 2.7.3
> 2. The `Numpy` version installed on the cluster is: `NumPy` version 1.6.2
> 3. `GCC version: GCC 4.6.1`
> 4. nose version 1.3.4

I installed Theano in the following manner

> 1. `git clone git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git`
> 2. `cd Theano; python2.7 setup.py install --user`
> 3. The installed Theano version is: 0.6.0

I then tried to run theano.test() inside a python2.7 console. The test ran smoothly for a couple of minutes before I got the following errors:

```
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: local_dot_to_dot22
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1491, in process_node
    replacements = lopt.transform(node)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/tensor/blas.py", line 1693, in local_dot_to_dot22
    return [_dot22(*node.inputs)]
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/op.py", line 537, in __call__
    no_recycling=[])
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/op.py", line 722, in make_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1043, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cc.py", line 985, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1423, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, fn=self.compile_cmodule_by_step, keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 1005, in module_from_key
    module = next(compile_steps)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1338, in compile_cmodule_by_step
    preargs=preargs)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 2011, in compile_str
    return dlimport(lib_filename)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 289, in dlimport
    rval = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, [module_name])
ImportError: ('~/.theano/compiledir_Linux-2.6.18-371.9.1.el5-x86_64-with-redhat-5.10-Tikanga-x86_64-2.7.3-64/tmpmlJ34P/eb163660e6e45b373cd7909e14efd44a.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_write_done', '[Dot22(<TensorType(float64, col)>, <TensorType(float64, row)>)]')
```

Please help me install Theano correctly. I have come across solutions on this group suggesting re-installing the latest version of Theano. However, I have already installed Theano from the git repository. I have tried this possible solution already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238732/4416268 but still I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Theano flag: `blas.ldflags=-lblas -lgfortran`

If you do not know how to use Theano flag, check this page: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html

Your problem is discussed on that page: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html